# Making drop down menu a Required field

Tags: javascript, menu, require

I'm using a CMS where the following code result in a drop down menu:

```
 <div class="control-group">
 <label class="control-label" for="region"><?php _e('Region'); ?></label>
 <div class="controls">
 <?php ItemForm::region_select(osc_get_regions()); ?>
 </div>
 </div>
```

The result is the word 'Region:' followed by a drop down menu with all the neighborhoods taken from 'osc_get_regions'

This is all handled by the CMS and I add neighborhoods to the osc_get_region through the admin panel.

I want to be able to make this drop down menu a required field. I did some research and believe I need to add a javascript code but I am not well versed in programming. - Any help on that would be much appreciated.

Thank you

edit:

-When I surround the code with , a new text field appears instead of requiring an item from the drop down menu to be selected.

-Omni5cience, I did install that plugin, but it only works for a normal text field. It did not enforce its requirement with the drop down menu. The code for that script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    if( $("form[name=item]")[b].length > 0[/b] ) {
    $('input[id="region"]').addClass("{required: true, messages: { required: '<?php  _e("Region is required", "location_required") ; ?>'}}") ;
```

Any suggestions for manipulating on that for a drop down menu? thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using an `<input>` tag?

Comment: Can you show how the form looks in html after it has been processed?

Comment: The code for this CMS looks really brittle, and as far as I can tell there's not an especially clean way to do what you're looking for. I did find a plugin that does some really basic client-side validation https://github.com/osclass/plugin-location_required

Comment: Omni5cience, I did install that plugin, but it only works for a normal text field. It did not enforce its requirement with the drop down menu. The code for that script is:<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
         if( $("form[name=item]")[b].length > 0[/b] ) {
                $('input[id="region"]').addClass("{required: true, messages: { required: '<?php _e("Region is required", "location_required") ; ?>'}}") ;

Any suggestions for manipulating on that for a drop down menu? thanks